# It is possible to gain muscular endurance in two weeks?

Tags: exercise, muscle-endurance

I live at south of Spain and we have extremely hot summers. Because of that I did almost any exercise during 3 mounts.

I practice long sword fencing and we did some training last Sunday and I noticed that I have lost a lot of fitness and what is worse muscular endurance. After few minutes of combat I could barely rise my arms. The problem is that we have a big event in two weeks.

It is possible to gain muscular endurance in such sort time ? what kind of exercises I should do ?

Comment: Since we can't quantify "muscular endurance", or the amount of it you can gain in two weeks, this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: maybe it is not quantifiable but I am not asking about quantity I as asking if it is possible to improve in short amount of time.

Comment: It is possible to improve in ANY amount of time. But it happens in such small increments, that it might not be enough to be noticable in two weeks.

Comment: Prior to this holiday, how long had you been training?

Comment: @JJosaur define training XD. I am practising since November but not regularly because of many reasons. But it is an martial art with weapons! and a it is huge strength equalizer. But every thing weights and also the heat doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibile but not that much.

Two weeks are yet only two weeks. Your case has a problem: that you've been inactive for a long period of time.

You can't provide a tremendous amount of workload just from nowhere; you must at least restart the machine and try to acquire all lost physical skills ( flexibility, strenght, and conditional capacities ).

It also depends on you as individual and how you tolerate training loads and how your body responds to them.